# Z3: Difference logic performance

Tags: logic, z3, difference

I have a problem to solve that can be translated into difference logic, and rather than implementing a decision procedure, I would like to use z3 for this purpose.
Nevertheless, I run a few examples and I had exponential-like runtimes (even though there is a polytime decision procedure for it). I am new to z3 and I dont know if I am doing something wrong. Here is the code that I am using (c++ api), varing this "max" variable.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
context c;

solver s(c, "QF_IDL");

int max = 10000;
int prev = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < max; ++i){
    expr x = s.ctx().int_const(std::to_string(i).c_str());
    expr y = s.ctx().int_const(std::to_string(++i).c_str());
    expr pr = s.ctx().int_const(std::to_string(prev).c_str());
    s.add(pr < x);
    s.add(x < y);
    prev = i;
}

s.add(s.ctx().int_const(std::to_string(max-1).c_str()) < s.ctx().int_const(std::to_string(0).c_str()));

clock_t begin = clock();
switch (s.check()) {
    case unsat:   std::cout << "UNSAT"; break;
    case sat:     std::cout << "SAT"; break;
    case unknown: std::cout << "unknown\n"; break;
}

clock_t end = clock();
double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_secs;
}
```

Many thanks in advance,

Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Z3 uses the simplex engine and sometimes a Floyd Marshall engine to solve your constraints even when the logic is QF_IDL. In this case it uses the simplex engine, and the size of rows grows quadratically for this example.
You can force the sparce difference logic solver by inserting the following into your program:

```
 params p(c);
 p.set("auto_config", false);
 p.set("smt.arith.solver", (unsigned)1);
 solver s(c, "QF_IDL");
 s.set(p);
```

This sets the arithmetic solver to the sparse difference logic solver.
It does not suffer from space overhead. It still takes quadratic time,
or to be more precise time proportional to |V|*|E| where |V| is the number
of variables and |E| are the number of inequalities. 
The main time bottleneck in this case is on big-num arithmetic, which is not
necessary in your case. I added an update to the unstable branch of Z3 so that it recognizes scenarios that only use small integers so that it can use a 
more efficient representation. This takes time on the larger examples down by a factor of about 5. Nevertheless, the overhead is still |V|*|E|.